# Why is my WHILE loop not reading all the table rows from the database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This code is supposed to be simple.

I have 8 rows of data from the database.

I am trying to use code below to read them and display them.

So far, the code is reading only 7, ignoring the very first row.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Protected Sub getRecords()
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim vimeoURL As String
    Dim VideoTitle As String
    Dim VideoDescription As String
    Dim sqlStr As String = ""

Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString

sqlStr = "SELECT [url], [Title], [Description] FROM [VIDEOS]"

cnn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
cnn.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlStr, cnn)
Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If dr.Read() Then
    Do While (dr.Read())
        vimeoURL = dr.GetString(0)
        VideoTitle = dr.GetString(1)
        VideoDescription = dr.GetString(2)

        Dim literal As New LiteralControl()
        literal.Text += (Convert.ToString("<a class='fancybox' data-fancybox-group='group01' title='" & VideoTitle & "' data-fancybox-type='iframe' href='#' onclick=""window.open('" & vimeoURL & "' , 'myWin', 'width=780,height=600,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,statu s=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes'); return false""><img src='images/thumb-vimeo-video.jpg' />'<br /><b>" & VideoTitle & "</b><br />" & VideoDescription & "</a></><br /><br />"))
        div1.Controls.Add(literal)
    Loop
End If
dr.Close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because you call dr.Read() twice, and that everytime you call it, it advances to the next row.

You don't really need the call to `If dr.Read()`, the while condition will take care of it.

Cheers

EDIT:

Here's your code rewritten:

```
Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString

sqlStr = "SELECT [url], [Title], [Description] FROM [VIDEOS]"

cnn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
cnn.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlStr, cnn)
Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Do While (dr.Read())
        vimeoURL = dr.GetString(0)
        VideoTitle = dr.GetString(1)
        VideoDescription = dr.GetString(2)

        Dim literal As New LiteralControl()
        literal.Text += (Convert.ToString("<a class='fancybox' data-fancybox-group='group01' title='" & VideoTitle & "' data-fancybox-type='iframe' href='#' onclick=""window.open('" & vimeoURL & "' , 'myWin', 'width=780,height=600,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,statu s=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=yes'); return false""><img src='images/thumb-vimeo-video.jpg' />'<br /><b>" & VideoTitle & "</b><br />" & VideoDescription & "</a></><br /><br />"))
        div1.Controls.Add(literal)
    Loop
dr.Close()
```

Comment: I am just so silly. I had initially tried FOR loop and was getting 7 rows instead of 8. Then rather than try WHILE loop, I jumbled the code.

Thanks a lot. It is working now.